# Using sed, extract text between first occurrence of a word1 and last occurrence of a word2

Tags: sed

I need to extract text between the first occurrence of a word called "BEGIN" and the last occurrence of a word called "END" using sed.

**Input:**

```
line1
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
line9
line10
```

**Expected Output:**

```
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
```

**My approach:**

It extracts text between BEGIN and END. Here there are two BEGIN & END statement, and my solution extracts text between these words.
My solution fails to extract text between first occurence of word1 (BEGIN) and last occurence of word2 (END).

```
dsonachalam$ sed -n -e '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/p' logs.txt
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
```

Comment: You have basically buffer the lines from the last END till the next in hold space. #1. Find BEGIN. #2. Find END. #3. Buffer each line in hold space. #4. If you the lines is END, then print hold space, clear hold space and go to step 3.

Comment: Anything involving finding the last X in a file is easier with `ed`: `printf "%s\n" "/BEGIN/,?END?p" | ed -s logs.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start=$(grep -n "BEGIN" $FILE_NAME |cut -f1 -d:|head -n 1)
end=$(grep -n "END" $FILE_NAME |cut -f1 -d:|tail -n 1)

sed -n $start,"$end"p $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: you can also use `sed -n '/BEGIN/='` and `sed -n '/END/='` instead of `grep + cut` ... and `sed -n '/BEGIN/ {=; q;}'` to avoid `head` as well

Comment: Copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for some issues. Also, that would read the input file 3 times and spawn 7 subshells which is excessive.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small enough to fit memory:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print /(^BEGIN\n.*^END\n)/ms' ip.txt
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
```

Answer (score 1):

With a 2-pass approach to avoid having to store any text in memory so it'll work for any size input file and with 1 call to 1 standard UNIX tool to avoid spawning multiple subshells, the following will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR{ if (!beg && /BEGIN/) beg=NR; if (/END/) end=NR; next}
    (beg <= FNR) && (FNR <= end)
' file file
BEGIN
line2
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner `sed` command would suffice (using GNU `sed`):

```
sed -E '/^BEGIN$/,$!d; :a; /(^|\n).*END$/{p;d}; $d; N; ba'
```

`/^BEGIN$/,$!d;` deletes lines above the first *BEGIN*. `:a; /(^|\n).*END$/{p;d}; $d; N; ba` accumulates ("slurps") lines into pattern space. Whenever an *END* line is read then the accumulated lines are printed out and pattern space is deleted starting a new cycle. Note that this "slurping" approach may be slow, or even may crash the `sed` process if the input is too large.

Content of input file:

```
line1
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
line9
line10
```

and using GNU sed 4.8

```
sed -E '/^BEGIN$/,$!d; :a; /(^|\n).*END$/{p;d}; $d; N; ba' inputfile
```

prints

```
BEGIN
line2 
line3
END
line4
line5
BEGIN
line6
line7
ENDED
END
line8
END
```

Another approach would be:

```
lastend=$(sed -n '/^END$/=' inputfile | tail -1)
[[ -n $lastend ]] && sed -n "/^BEGIN\$/,${lastend}p" inputfile
```

This two-pass approach doesn't suffer from "slurping" lines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\<BEGIN\>/{x;:a;n;/\<END\>/{x;p;ba};H;$!ba;x;//P}' file
```

Set automatic printing off by using the `-n` option and then focus on lines following one that contains the word `BEGIN`.

Swap to the hold space (HS) and initiate a loop that fetches the next line and if that line contains the word `END` swap to the HS, print its contents and repeat.

If the current line does not contain the word `END`, append the current line to the HS and unless it is the end of file repeat.

At the end of file, print the first line of the HS if it begins `END` and whatever the condition allow the file processing to terminate.

Thus processing of lines only occurs once the word `BEGIN` has been seen and printing of those lines every time the word `END` occurs.